# Broken php package in apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, php7

I want to install php7.4-soap on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, so I ran `sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap`

But I get following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-soap : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu1) but 7.4.5-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I deal with this error?

Comment: Looks like you have a PPA mixed in.

Comment: Yes, I have already added PPA by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`.

Comment: Post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, is it appear you have 19.10 source.

Comment: I faced this same problem yesterday.
I realized it was because I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04
Try re-adding the PPA and reinstall PHP if the problem persists.